# In React.js, how to show "Not Found" page if the network request returns 404 status in the componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have `Route` to handle unknown URLs and that `Route` works fine and renders the `PageNotFound` perfectly. But, I have a different scenario, here I am having a `Profile` component where on component mount, I have to send a ajax request to the server to fetch the user's profile.
E.g if the URL is http://localhost:3007/profile/theCoder the a ajax request would be send to the server http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles/theCoder. A normal stuff every website is doing, but I want to know how do I show a 404 Page i.e `PageNotFound` component if the ajax return a `404 status`? Means if the `theCoder` user doesn't exists?
I handled it using `history.push("/some-wrong-route")` which would render the `PageNotFound`, but the browser URL also gets change to http://localhost:3007/profile/some-wrong-route

I don't want this, I want a right behavior from my application like other websites do. They keep the same URL but renders the PageNotFound.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const responsePromise = fetchUserProfileMinimal(this.props.match.params.id);
    responsePromise
      .then(({ data }) => {
           //do something
        })
      .catch(err => {
        this.props.history.push("/hello");
      });
  }

  render(){
     return{
        <div>.....</div>
     }

  }
```

Routes:

```
<Route component={PageNotFound} />
<Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe set a flag on the `state` to indicate that you got a 404 from the ajax request, and then render appropriate content from the `render()` method by checking that flag?

Comment: I thought of this solution, but I doubt if state would be right choice to handle this requirement.

Comment: Well the issue is that your setup means that you have to mount the component, send a request to verify if they are present to then determine if it's a 404 or not. The only way I could see you doing it would be to have a loading state, successful state and error state where each state would render some relevant different UI.

Comment: @TomFinney If it were you, how would have you handled it? Where would you prefer to make API request to fetch the user info? I used `componentDidMount` as I have read it in some threads.